# Running multiple, simple linear regressions against the same primary variable in R

Tags: r, linear-regression

I have a data.frame (let's call it DF) loaded in to R that essentially looks like the following:

```
         primary_variable     var1     var2     var3     var4...     var354
sample1      5                    1        4        3        2       1
sample2      8                    2        3        4        1       2
sample3      7                    3        2        1        4       3
sample4      2                    4        1        2        3       4
.
.
.
sample58     8                    1        2        3        4
```

Basically, I want to run simple linear regression multiple times, comparing the primary variable and all the others individually as follows:

```
reg <- lm(primary_variable~var1, data=DF)
reg <- lm(primary_variable~var2, data=DF)
reg <- lm(primary_variable~var3, data=DF)
reg <- lm(primary_variable~var354, data=DF)
```

And have the data output in to a table of some sort so that I can read the P values for them all.

What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to do this:

```
DF <- read.table(text="         primary_variable     var1     var2     var3     var4
sample1      5                    1        4        3        2
sample2      8                    2        3        4        1
sample3      7                    3        2        1        4
sample4      2                    4        1        2        3", header=TRUE)

sapply(DF[,-1], function(x) summary(lm(DF[,1]~x))$coef[,"Pr(>|t|)"])

#                  var1     var2      var3     var4
# (Intercept) 0.1471971 0.477767 0.4023857 0.206388
# x           0.5120500 0.512050 0.7072300 0.707230
```

However, I strongly advise you not to do this. Please seek help from a statistician.

Comment: I'm upvoting the advice at the end. (This must be duplicated many times on SO.)